# How to make any DIRECTORY WRITABLE , on heroku?

Tags: heroku, directory, writable

How to make any DIRECTORY WRITABLE , on heroku ??

because I make an app on facebook , with heroku hosting 
but there is some DIRECTORY should be WRITABLE to run my app .

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku doesn't allow you to write directly to the filesystem.  It's because of the way they deploy each app as a self-contained 'slug'.  If you want to write files you'll need to use something like Amazon's S3 or serialize the data and save it to the database.